# Installing mwe package

Tags: installing, mwe

I am running a version of ubuntu that has TexLive 2009, which apparently does not come with tlmgr, so I have to install packages manually. I have done this before (extract to /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex and then run texhash /usr/share/texmf), but for this package,

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe

I did that, but it still complains that it can't find mwe.sty. You can see in that list of files that mwe.sty is actually not there. I read that with this ins/dtx pair, I am supposed to run

```
latex mwe.ins
```

but I am getting this error:

```
doriad@david-lab:~/temp/mwe$ latex mwe.ins
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./mwe.ins
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
! I can't find file `ydocstrip'.
l.1 \input ydocstrip

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name:
```

Any thoughts on how to install this package?

Comment: How about using either the [TeX live 2012 backports](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012) or [Vanilla TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html)?

Comment: @Silex Ah, great. But I am still curious what I am doing wrong here (in case I ever come across another ins/dtx pair that I need to install.

Comment: Do you have the [ydoc package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ydoc)?

Comment: @Silex Awesome, I installed ydoc (tex ydoc.dtx), and then the mwe install went as expected. Thanks! If you make "install ydoc" an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Note - you have to have the files that 'tex ydoc.dtx' generates in the same folder as mwe.ins before running 'latex mwe.ins'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're missing `ydocstrip`. It's included in the [ydoc package.](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ydoc)